# Parsing a file of hex characters and storing in a buffer

Tags: c, file, io

i am trying to read a txt file containing strictly only hex characters (bytes so guaranteed to be even number of characters). But i am getting stuck in a loop and the program does not end. I am using fgetc() to read in characters and then store it as byte sized array as follows

```cpp
uint32_t hexadecimal_to_int(char *ch)
{
  uint32_t val = 0;
  while (*ch)
  {
    // get current character then increment
    uint8_t byte = *ch++;
    // transform hex character to the 4bit equivalent number, using the ascii table indexes
    if (byte >= '0' && byte <= '9')
      byte = byte - '0';
    else if (byte >= 'a' && byte <= 'f')
      byte = byte - 'a' + 10;
    else if (byte >= 'A' && byte <= 'F')
      byte = byte - 'A' + 10;
    // shift 4 to make space for new digit, and add the 4 bits of the new digit
    val = (val << 4) | (byte & 0xF);
  }
  return val;
}

uint32_t read_file(FILE *file, uint8_t **buf)
{
  uint8_t val;
  uint32_t size = 0;
  char c1;
  char c2;
  char byte[3] = {0, 0, '\0'};
  int64_t startpos = ftell(file);
  while (c1 = fgetc(file) != '\n' && c1 != EOF) 
  {
    c2 = fgetc(file);
    ++size;
  }
  *buf = (uint8_t *)malloc(size);
  fseek(file, startpos, SEEK_SET); 
  int32_t pos = 0;
  while (((c1 = fgetc(file)) != '\n') && (c1 != EOF))
  {
    c2 = fgetc(file);
    byte[0] = c1;
    byte[1] = c2;
    (*buf)[pos++] = hexadecimal_to_int(byte);
  }
  return size;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
....
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid file error!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  uint8_t *buffer= {0};
  uint8_t buf_size = read_file(fp, &buffer); // LOOPING HERE, DONT KNOW WHY
...
```

The text file contains

```
7059601457124761739001010010D10122011143878089905F201A564953412041435155495245522054455354204341524420323957114761739001010010D101220111438780899F1F10313134333830303738303030303030309000
```

Funny thing is for some permutations of contents in file it works as expected. Not sure whats wrong

Comment: Tip: Save time and enable all warnings.  `while (c1 = fgetc(file) != '\n' && c1 != EOF)` resulted in "warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]" hinting at a problem.

Comment: Iberico, Aside: Why code `int64_t startpos = ftell(file);` and not `long startpos = ftell(file);` since `ftell()` retruns a `long`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i didn't think much of it as the platform i am on uses 64 bits for a long. But i guess i should have just stuck to long to be safe. Yeah, by default gcc doesn't on warnings. That's actually a good tip that i will keep in mind, thanks!

Comment: Try `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wformat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
while (c1 = fgetc(file) != '\n' && c1 != EOF)
```

is missing some parentheses.  Make it:

```
while ((c1 = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && c1 != EOF)
```

and change the type of `c1` and `c2` to `int`.  (`fgetc` returns an `int`, and you lose information by assigning to a `char`.  The comparison `c1 != EOF` is no longer reliable.)  The original line is equivalent to:

```
while (c1 = (fgetc(file) != '\n' && c1 != EOF) )
```

which is undefined behavior since `c1` is not initialized, and the attempt to read its value in the comparison `c1 != EOF` is invalid.